# Local variable referenced before

Tags: arrays

I have an array of data which in the first column has years, and the other 3 columns has data for 3 different groups, the last of which is carrots.

I am trying to find the year in which the carrot value is the highest, by comparing the carrot value each year to the current highest, and then finding the year that the value takes place on.

I have used identical code for the other 2 columns with just the word carrot replaced and i in year[i] changed appropriately and the code works, but for this it throws up the error "local variable 'carrot_maxyear' referenced before assignment"

```
def carrot(data):
    year0 = data[0]
    carrotmax = year0[3]
    for year in data:
        if year[3] > carrotmax:
            carrotmax = year[3]
            carrot_maxyear = year[0] 
    return carrot_maxyear
```

Comment: You may want to tag this with the language as well

Comment: What if data is empty or no year greater than carrotmax? Then there will be no assignment

Answer (score 1):

Python's builtin [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max) will make this easier:

```py
def carrot(data):
  maxyear = max(data, key=lambda year: year[3])
  return maxyear[0]
```

This way you don't need the `year0` and `carrotmax` initialization. We need to use the `key` argument to `max` because it looks like you want to return `year[0]` instead of the `year[3]` value used for the max calculation.

Your original version with a fix would look like:

```py
def carrot(data):
    year0 = data[0]
    carrotmax = year0[3]
    carrot_maxyear = 0  # initialize carrot_maxyear outside of loop to avoid error
    for year in data:
        if year[3] > carrotmax:
            carrotmax = year[3]
            carrot_maxyear = year[0] 
    return carrot_maxyear
```

but IMO the version utilizing `max` is more clear and Pythonic.